# C#, cannot close second form

Tags: c#

i am experiencing strange problem in c#, i have 2 forms, wForm and FormOverlay, on the FormOverlay i've text that i want to print/draw on the x process. To make this work i've checkbox as well. And this is my code

```
public void Overlay()
        {
            FormOverlay fo = new FormOverlay();

            if (Watermark.Checked)
            {
                fo.Show();
            }
            else if (!Watermark.Checked)
            {
                fo.Close();
            }
        }
```

The problem i face now is that when i press on checkbox again my second form does not want to close. So far i tried to make another method and use Environment.Exit(0); then i realised this close the entire application, not just 2nd form. Any ideas how to fix this ?

Kind Regards.

Comment: That is because you create a new one each time you call `Overlay`, you don't want to do that. Store a reference as a class field and use that.

Comment: Side note: `if (condition) {DoSomething} else if (!condition) {DoSomethingElse}` can _and should_ be replaced with `if (condition) {DoSomething} else {DoSomethingElse}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you create a new object each time. In order to close an existing object, you need to store a reference to it:

```
    private FormOverlay _myOverlay;

    public void Overlay()
    {
        if (Watermark.Checked)
        {
            _myOverlay = new FormOverlay();
            _myOverlay.Show();
        }
        else  //The "if (!Watermark.Checked) is redundant here
        {
            _myOverlay?.Close();
            _myOverlay?.Dispose();  //Please dispose of your waste properly
            _myOverlay = null;
        }
    }
```

This will make sure that you are using the same reference.

Comment: Thank you very much Ron Beyer, your code works like a charm. Will definitely keep that in mind :)

Answer (score 1):

Look at this line:

```
FormOverlay fo = new FormOverlay();
```

especially this keyword:

```
new
```

You're working with a different instance of your form every time that code runs. You need to add code to the class for this method that will keep a reference around for the same instance of your form, and only create a `new` instance if you don't already have one.

Comment: Thank you both, Joel Coehoorn and Ron Beyer.I am kinda new into C#. I will keep that in mind next time i am trying to do something similar. Thank you very much for the detailed solution